# How to hide easy access to my website temporarily?

Tags: security

I am developing a new website and I do not want others, except for my colleagues, to access it easily. I don't want it to be password protected because my colleagues are testing it intensively. Is there any simple way to obfuscate it, so that I will not need to install WP into another folder etc.? More specifically, is there any simple way to ban access to http://www.example.com and virtually move the main page to, let's say, http://www.example.com/h6DuBo93yS? The rest of pages can remain, since their addresses are not very easy to guess.

Comment: Put an ip check at the top of functions.php.

Comment: The fastest way is to just create a folder like `/h6DuBo93yS`, moving files around isn't that hard and it beats most other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this you have to change **Post Visibility Settings**
This can be done when you are posting a post.
just see on right side or near publish button
there will be a visibility option which is public by default this can be edited..
    Visibility: Public

just click edit and choose password protected radio botton and give a password of your choice
  That all.

But wait if you don't want it to be password protected then change the Permalink Setting in setting
and create a custom URL or your choice..
That'a all

Comment: IMHO neither of your suggestions solves my problem: www.example.com will still be accessible and will display reasonable (although not full) context. Not only post content matters but site structure and layout etc. as well.

Comment: Have you tried to change Permalink Setting to a custom URL

Comment: How could this help with hiding http://www.example.com/ ?

Comment: By changing Permalink To a custom structure / post name/category or tag base etc...   the url for a post changes to example.com/your_structure

Comment: By doing this whenever a Post is not found The 404.php template file is by default called and page is displayed using the 404.php

Comment: Hey try to change the site URL from setting  and look at [wordpress doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Answer (score -1):

Lots of plugins out there for this - I recommend [Ultimate Coming Soon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/). Flip of a switch allows you to give all non-logged-in users a message instead of seeing the site. Only draw-back is if you need to do any non-logged-in testing.

Comment: This is merely a recommendation, and doesn't actually answer the question. Can you explain how the plugin does it? How would I implement my own version of that plugin at its simplest case? How does it perform the edge case the asker specified?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatelly, great part of testing consists of testing of the registration/login process and of access of unregistered users to the site content.